# Error: Variadic template class has incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae

I have the code:

```
#include <unordered_set>

template<typename First, typename Enable = void, typename ... T>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor;

template<typename ... T>
bool converged_is_exactly_equal(const T& ...);

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
bool is_exactly_equal(const T other, const T one) {
    return (other == one);
}

template<typename First, typename ... T>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 1>, T ...>
{
    private:
        static std::unordered_set<First*> visited_values;
        void visit_value (const First& value_to_visit) {
            visited_values.insert(&value_to_visit);
        }
        bool is_visited (const First& value_to_check) {
            return (visited_values.find(&value_to_check) != visited_values.end());
        }
    public:
        converged_is_exactly_equal_functor(void){}
        bool operator () (const First& first_arg, const T& ... expanded_args) const {
            if (!is_visited(first_arg)) {
                visit_value(first_arg);
                return is_exactly_equal(first_arg, expanded_args ...);
            }
            return true;
        }
};

template<typename First, typename ... T>
std::unordered_set<First*> converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 1>, T ...>::visited_values;

template<typename First, typename ... T>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) != 1>, T ...>
{
    public:
        converged_is_exactly_equal_functor(void){}
        bool operator () (const First& first_arg, const T& ... expanded_args) const {
            return is_exactly_equal(first_arg, expanded_args ...);
        }
};

template<typename ... T>
bool converged_is_exactly_equal(const T& ... expanded_args) {
    converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<T ... > my_functor;
    return my_functor(expanded_args ...);
}

class a {
    public:
    a() : dbid(1), lsb(123) {}
    int dbid;
    long lsb;
};


bool operator == (const a& other, const a& one) {
    if (&other == &one)
        return true;
    return (
        converged_is_exactly_equal(other.dbid, one.dbid) &&
        converged_is_exactly_equal(other.lsb, one.lsb)
    );
}

int main(void) {
a as, bs;

as == bs;
}
```

Given that **class a** is simple group of primitive types, why am I receiving the following error:

```
my_file.cxx: In instantiation of 'bool converged_is_exactly_equal(const T& ...) [with T = {long int, long int}]':
my_file.cxx:690:56:   required from here
my_file.cxx:682:48: error: 'converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<long int, long int> my_functor' has incomplete type
     converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<T ... > my_functor;
```

I believe the error has nothing to do with the proprietary data structures, but I don't see why the type could be incomplete. I have the header file for unordered_set included in this same file.

All definitions of **is_exactly_equal(T)** are done between the forward declarations and the templates' definitions.

Please be as explicit as possible, since I tend to find it complicated to understand template errors in general.

I can provide any more information necessary, but I'll only be back tomorrow. (This one has drained me out :-/)

Comment: Please provide the code that instantiates the template as well. And I assume `operator==` is supposed to be templated?

Comment: I don't understand. I believe the code that instantiates the template is there.
"operator==" is defined one by one, since it covers member comparison for each different struct.

Comment: Without an instantiation, it seems to compile [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/njTch3). (I made `operator==` a template). It's not a member of a class template in the provided code. Of course, it's possible *I'm* misunderstanding the question.

Comment: What's being asked for is a [mre] that we can compile ourselves to reproduce the error. In order to even see if we get the same error, each of us needs to add appropriate includes and pick a way of dealing with that missing class used in `operator==`.

Comment: I have added the main and instantiation producing the same error. Will update the question.

Comment: You forget the second template parameter `typename Enable = void` that is part of the interface. If it's not `void` (`long int` here), the non-defined general form is selected.

Comment: Sorry, the site went down for me. I'll update the code with a complete example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `converged_is_exactly_equal_functor` class and in it's use.

You declare it as follows

```
template<typename First, typename Enable = void, typename ... T>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor;
```

without defining it.

Then you define two specializations: one for the case `sizeof...(T) == 1`

```
template<typename First, typename ... T>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 1>, T ...>
{
  // ...
};
```

and one for the case `sizeof...(T) != 1`

```
template<typename First, typename ... T>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) != 1>, T ...>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

You use the class inside `converged_is_exactly_equal`

```
template<typename ... T>
bool converged_is_exactly_equal(const T& ... expanded_args) {
    converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<T ... > my_functor;
    return my_functor(expanded_args ...);
}
```

that is called, in your programs, two times

```
    converged_is_exactly_equal(other.dbid, one.dbid) &&
    converged_is_exactly_equal(other.lsb, one.lsb)
```

The first time with two `int`, the second time with two `long`.

In both case, you declare a `converged_is_exactly_equal_functor` value with a second template parameter that isn't `void`, so doesn't matches the specialization, so matches the main template but the main template is declared but not defined.

So the error.

A possible solution: throw away the SFINAE part and simply declare/define the class for a variadic list of following types (the old `sizeof...(T) != 0`)

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor
 {
   public:
      converged_is_exactly_equal_functor ()
       { }

      bool operator () (F const & fa, Ts const & ... ea) const
       { return is_exactly_equal(fa, ea ...); }
 };
```

and define a specialization for two cases only (the old `sizeof...(T) == 1` case)

```
template <typename First, typename Second>
class converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, Second>
 {
   private:
      static std::unordered_set<First const *> visited_values;

      void visit_value (First const & value_to_visit) const
       { visited_values.insert(&value_to_visit); }

      bool is_visited (First const & value_to_check) const
       { return (visited_values.find(&value_to_check) != visited_values.end()); }

   public:
      converged_is_exactly_equal_functor ()
       { }

      bool operator () (First const & fa, Second const & sa) const
       {
            if ( false == is_visited(fa) )
             {
               visit_value(fa);

               return is_exactly_equal(fa, sa);
             }

            return true;
        }
 };

template <typename First, typename Second>
std::unordered_set<First const *> converged_is_exactly_equal_functor<First, Second>::visited_values;
```

Observe that I've added some `const` to let it compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The proposed solution resolved my issue and kept the code intent.
I did not know that I could specialize it based on the number of arguments alone, thought that would be an ambiguity haha.

Comment: @thiago - There isn't an ambiguity because the specialization is "more specialized" than the main version. Roughly speaking: a template A is "more specialized" than a template B when all parameter sets matching A match also B but there is at least a set of parameters that matches B but don't matches A. In our case, a two types set ever matches both templates but a three types matches the main template but not the specialization.